# Eigen Decomposition of a symmetric matrix is not checking out

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra.
I am trying to express a symmetric matrix in terms of its eigen decomposition.
Given  a symmetric matrix  $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{bmatrix}$
Then the eigenvectors are $x_1=[1,1]^T$ and $x_2= [-1,1]^T$ with respective eigenvalues  $\lambda_1 =5$ and  $\lambda_2 = -1$.

Then we know $A = Q \lambda Q^{-1}$ or $A = Q\lambda Q^T.\tag 1$

Here, $Q$ ,which is made of eigenvectors, that is ,$Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ should be orthogonal but it is not as $Q^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}$ and
$Q^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ . In short $Q^{-1}=\frac12Q^T$, which is contradicting equation $(1)$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To achieve $Q^{-1}=Q^T$ you need to have an ortho**normal** system of eigenvectors: A) you need to normalize them to unit vectors, B) if there is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $>1$ then you need to run Gram-Schmidt (or something similar) to a basis of the eigenspace.